# copy different ranges of data from different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro which copies data from different worksheets in their respective workbooks, and then paste over another worksheet. The problem is due to different formats of data in different worksheets, so I need to extract different ranges of data for different worksheets. But my script is only able to extract from one specific range I set, it skips other `if` I set for it.

Here is my code for selecting different ranges of data, it only manages to copy range of A1 to B2 for all files:

```
' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:B2")
                ' Change Range if B1 value is "Host Name"
                If .Range("B1") = "Host Name" Then

                    '// Here lets Find the last row of data
                    wSlastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    '// Now Loop through each row
                    For X = 4 To wSlastRow

                        Set sourceRange = .Union(Range("B" & (X)), Range("C" & (X)))

                    Next X
                End If
            End With
```

Here is the screenshots for different worksheet formats:

The first picture reflects my if case above, when macro reads "Host name" at B1, it should copy column B and C starting from row 4, until it finds a blank row.

[image]

The second picture is the normal case where data contained in A1 and A2 cells.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear (to me at least) what specific problem you are having.  Can you more clearly state your problem?  Your code appears to generate a `sourceRange` which contains columns `B` and `C` for a single row.  Are you trying to output those values to a new worksheet?  Do you have other code to do that?

Comment: @Byron Hi I just edited the question, let me know if there's anything need to edit:) Now my problem is my script is only able to extract data from Range("A1:B2") for all worksheets. However, you could look at the if case in my code, that is set specifically for the first picture format, I don't know why the system never uses my if case.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at that line and see what is says the value of `.Range("B1")` is.  It is possible that it contains a space or some other character that prevents equality.  Step through and verify that it is not entering the `If` block.  I see no good reason it would not enter the `If`.

Comment: @Byron it doesn't tell me anything for `.Rnage("B1")`, I have tried `.Range("B1").Value`, it all didn't work, I think it didn't enter `if` though.